# Moya and Alamofire strange time out error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, moya

I currently using Moya and Alamofire for get data from server for iOS. and it worked perfectly before. However, only ios can't get data for some unknown reasons. for the postman and android is working for getting data from server.

if i just use Alamofire to get data is working but with moya is not working...

Does anyone knows or solved this problem?

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60400025fb90 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}

```
extension ServerRequestService: TargetType {
  var baseURL: URL { return URL(string: CRConstant.API.requestHostForProduction)! }

  var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .main: return "/main"
    }
  }

  var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .main: return .get
    }
  }

  var task: Task {
    switch self {
    case .main: var param = [String: Any](); param["device"] = IOS
      return .requestParameters(parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    }
  }

  ServerRequestService.request(.main) { [weak self] result in
    guard let `self` = self else {
      return
    }

    switch result {
    case let .success(response):
      print(response.data)
    case let .failure:
      print("failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: first check your parmeters and url properly

Comment: @tabassum i've checked it! its all fine and correct.... other requests are perfectly working but only one request is not working with that error

Comment: can you show me code ? how u r requesting?

Comment: extension ServerRequestService: TargetType {
  var baseURL: URL {
      return URL(string: CRConstant.API.requestHostForProduction)!
 var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .main
    return "/main"
}
  var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .main
    return .get
    }
  var task: Task {
    switch self {
 case .main:
      var param = [String: Any]()
      param["device"] = IOS
return .requestParameters(parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
   }
}

@tabassum

Comment: @tabassum uhmmm looks too unorganized.... if i write in the comment... :p

Comment: edited your question :)

Comment: @tabassum nah.. still looking for answer..

Comment: let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

manager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
try this set your timeinterval for your url request

Comment: @tabassum if i do like that is working but if i mix with moya not working..